# EF core get data from entity per day by limit

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This is an entity

```
public class ViewModel
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

This is my context query,works with ef core in dbcontext.

```
var list = _Service.GetDataByMonth(start,end).ToList();
// it returns all entity between giving start, end param.
// start and end is Datetime property comes from ajax. This code works fine it return almost 1k objectlist with type of ViewModel
```

like

```
[0] Id="1",Title="sample",Start:""15.12.2020"
[1] Id="2",Title="sample2",Start:""15.12.2020"
[2] Id="3",Title="sample3",Start:""16.12.2020"
[3] Id="4",Title="sample4",Start:""16.12.2020"
```

As shows above we got almost 20+ entity per day.

I can get count per day like

```
var listt = _Service.GetDataByMonth(start,end).GroupBy(x => x.Start.Date).Select(grp => new { Date = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() });
    [0] Key:""15.12.2020",Count:20
    [1] Key:""16.12.2020",Count:25
    [2] Key:""17.12.2020",Count:44
```

it returns like this.

So what i want is giving start and end param a funciton then get 3 values per day between giving datetime object

**NEW**

```
 var list1= _Service.GetDataByMonth(start,end).GroupBy(x => x.StartDate.Date)
                  .Select(grp => grp.Take(3)).ToList(); 
//this type List<Ienumerable<Viewmodel>>

var list2 = _Service.GetDataByMonth(start,end).GroupBy(x => x.StartDate.Date).Select(grp => grp.Take(3).ToList()).ToList();
// this type List<List<Viewmodel>>

My want it List<Viewmodel>
```

service

```
...
return entity.Where(x =>                        
                    x.IsDeleted == false &&                    
                    (x.StartDate.Date >= start.Date && x.StartDate.Date <=end.Date)
                    ).OrderBy(x => x.FinishDate).ToList();
```

// it work with this way but bad way

```
var lis = list.SelectMany(d => d).ToList();
```

Yes I figuredout using selectmany instead of select works fine. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Take()` to only take 3 items of each group:

```
_Service.GetDataByMonth(start,end)
   .GroupBy(x => x.Start.Date)
   .Select(grp => new { Data = grp.Take(3).ToList(), Date = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: But theres one more think. I make this after returned all value from database. Can i make it comes like this from database not after querying

Comment: well you need to apply this grouping wghen it is still Queryable (and not IEnumerable) so do this in your repository when querying from on your dbset.

Comment: it mades list of list object like List<List<Viewmodel>>. Should i put this query at then end of  using(var context = new DbContext) in  serviceManager. That should make it right

Comment: you should put it there (before `.ToList()`) as `.ToList()` will make it IEnumerable

Comment: But i dont want this type just made it just like <List<Viewmodel>

Comment: I know, I say you should add `.ToList()` (if you add it) after grouping

Comment: I will update quesiton in minute and show returned types.I updated you can check

Comment: What should i change

Comment: the change should be in your Service, can you post the code in service?

Comment: Okay I added service. Is this enough

Answer (score 0):

```
 var list1= _Service.GetDataByMonth(start,end).GroupBy(x => x.StartDate.Date)
                  .Select(grp => grp.Take(3)).ToList();
```

It returns List<List> maybe it will help some one bu my need is comes from with this code
This code makes list of list each element is list and contians 3 object.

```
 var list1= _Service.GetDataByMonth(start,end).GroupBy(x => x.StartDate.Date)
                  .SelectMany(grp => grp.Take(3)).ToList();
```

Many makes just list. It mades list with ordered objects